# how to get translation of taxonomy term in a preprocess function

Tags: transliteration

I am using `MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view` to assign the taxonomy term as the page title for all the entries of a content type. it's working fine but the issue is when I switch the language from English to Arabic the page content is translating correctly but the title still remains in English. While I have translated all the taxonomy terms. Here is my code.

```
/* Preprocess Function to print the taxonomy term as title for media_center bundle */
function kmtheme_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::request()->attributes->get('node');
  if ($node && $node->hasField('field_media_center') && !$node->field_media_center->isEmpty()) {
  }

  if ($node && $node->bundle() == 'media_center') {
    $term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($node->get('field_media_center')->target_id);
    $term_name = $term->getName();

    $variables['title'] = t($term_name);
  }
}
```

I want to get the translated value of the taxonomy term when the language switch from English to Arabic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page_title(&$variables) {

  // Get node.
  $node = getNode($variables);

  // Check for node and field.
  if ($node && $node->hasField("field_name") && !$node->get('field_name')->isEmpty()) {

    // Get term ID.
    $term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($node->get('field_name')->target_id);

    // Get current langcode.
    $langCode = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

    // Check for translation.
    if ($term->hasTranslation($langCode)) {

      // Get term from context.
      $term = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($term, $langCode);
    }

    // Get term name.
    $termName = $term->getName();

    // Set term name as title.
    $variables['title'] = t($termName);
  }
}
```

---

```
// I like checking for node contexts but not necessary for this question.
function getNode($variables = NULL) {

  $routeName = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();

  // $variables['node'].
  if (isset($variables['node'])) {
    if (is_numeric($variables['node'])) {
      return \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($variables['node']);
    }
    return $variables['node'];
  }

  // $variables['row'].
  if (isset($variables['row']) && !empty($variables['row']->nid)) {
    return \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($variables['row']->nid);
  }

  // Node canonical.
  if ($routeName === 'entity.node.canonical') {
    return \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  }

  // Node revision.
  if ($routeName === 'entity.node.revision') {
    $revisionId = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_revision');
    return node_revision_load($revisionId);
  }

  // Node preview.
  if ($routeName === 'entity.node.preview') {
    return \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node_preview');
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It's worked for me.